# When creating a Python package in PyPi how do I specify a path for the readme file

Tags: python-3.x, pypi

When creating my Python package I set the file name for my readme file in setup.cfg under the 'long_description' heading:

```
long_description = file: README.md
```

This assumes the README.md file is in the project's root directory.
How do I specify an alternative location?
I have unsucesfully tried:

```
long_description = file: Docs/README.md
```

Comment: why not have your README in the outermost dir? that's what people expect when opening  your package - you can even refer them to the Docs dir if you want to have a more in-depth documentation system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to explicitly include the path of my readme file by creating a `MANIFEST.in` file in my base directory with a directive that locates my readme file:

```
include Docs/README.md
```

Details of the MANIFEST.in file and associated directives are in https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/#using-manifest-in
The path still needs to be under the long_description heading in the `setup.cfg` file

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try:

```
long_description = open('your file').read()
```

Comment: I think your answer might work if I was using a setup.py file, but I am using setup.cfg. I tried it anyway within my setup.cfg file and it did not work.